# how to know JToolbar's status?

Tags: java, swing

How to check the JToolbar is docked on my JFrame or it is draged out with its own window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the isFloating() method from the BasicToolBarUI class.

Comment: but how can I get the BasicToolBarUI of the JToolBar? getUI() methed return ToolBarUI not the BasicToolBarUI.